# How to get div's centered next to each other in this Bootstrap 3 grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have 6 `div`s, each of which has a specific width in number of pixels. Using Bootstrap 3 I would like to have a maximum of 3 boxes on one row/line. As the screen gets smaller it should move to 2 `div`s on one line, and when it gets smaller even more just 1 `div` on a row. How can I do this?

I expected the code below to achieve this.
However, the `div`s displayed on one row unfortunately are not centered. *How to center these divs?*

```css
.mainDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.specificWidthInNumberOfPixels {
    border: 14px solid #dd5;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px; 
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
}

.float {
    float: left;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv container-fluid">

   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="">
     <p style="text-align: center;">Header</p>
   </div>

   <div class="row" style="max-width: 700px; float: none; display: table; margin: auto; background-color: #000;">

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 float">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 float">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 float">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 float">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 float">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 float">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

*Update:* In response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60443877/5086345): so the answer now produces the visual at the top, but instead what I'm looking for is the visual at the bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use CSS Grid, you're in good shape. Look on codepen to preview it, the code snippet seems like it's acting up:

https://codepen.io/tobyinternet/pen/bGdoBEr

```css
.mainDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.row-grid:before, .row-grid:after {
display: none;
}

.row-grid {
margin: 0 auto;
width:100%;
max-width: 500px;
display: grid !important;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,160px);
column-gap: 10px;
row-gap: 10px;
justify-content: center;
}

.specificWidthInNumberOfPixels {
    border: 14px solid #dd5;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px; 
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv container-fluid">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Header</p>
</div>

<div class="row row-grid" style="background-color: #000;">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to wrap them in a container-fluid or container class with a row child element, like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div class="specificWidthInNumberOfPixels">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will display 1 row of 3 columns. Add a second row within the container div with the same 3 columns to display a second row of 3 columns

Comment: But then it would for a smaller screen never display 2 div's next to each other on a row. So I would like it to display a maximum of 3 (out of 6) div's on a row, then if the screen is smaller it switches to 3 rows of 2 divs, and with an even smaller screen to 1 div a row.

Comment: Sorry, but this really doesn't work. I even made a codepen for it using your code, but I don't get columns next to each other.

Comment: See the following codepen: https://codepen.io/adamk22/pen/wvaqBwM - 3 items on desktop and 2 items on mobile. You can give the `.specificWidthInNumberOfPixels` a fixed width and height and it will behave the same.

Comment: Thanks, I see, but now I would like the boxes centered that are on the same row. So right next to each other with only padding/margin between them, and not spread out over the entire row.